# 13.10 headphones no sound

Tags: sound, 13.10, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I've tried the alsa force-reload, uninstall, re-install with `pulseaudio`, `killall pulseaudio`, the sound setting output configuration, alsamixer enable/disable automute, alsamixer output selection.

Headphones work, computer-side female jack possible hardware issue.

Sound level registering in sound settings when output set to headphones.

Internal speakers work fine.

What to do? am I missing drivers on a clean install?